# How can I add/show the Converted Amount in a quote?

Tags: quote, multi-currency, quote-template

We use Multiple Currencies.

We want, that once an oppty/quote is created in non standard currency, it will also show the converted total, as well as the exchange rate in the quote.

I don't have these fields when creating the quote template.

Is it possible?